# how to show textfields value from one view controller to another viewcontroller when button is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've implemented two `uiviewcontrollers`. I have some text fields in one on a `uiview` and 1 button on it. What I want is that when I fill text fields and click on the button, these values show on another `uiview` controller. I am facing a problem when I fill the text fields  and click on the button, another `uiview` on shows on the iPhone screen but the text field values are not shown on it. I also import `nextview.h` file in my `viewcontroller.m` file. Below is some of my code:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{


    nextview *NView = [[nextview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [[NView name] setText:name.text];
    [[NView fathername] setText:father.text];
    [[NView country] setText:countryselected.text];
    [[NView gender] setText:genderselected.text];
    [[NView dob] setText:dateselected.text];
    [[NView username] setText:username.text];
    [[NView password] setText:password.text];
    [[NView email] setText:email.text];
    [self presentModalViewController:NView animated:YES];

}
```

In the `nextview` class, I also define `@property` of uilabels in the .h file and I also `@synthesize`, `initialize` and `release` these labels in the `nextview.m` file and linked these variables to all labels. The problem is still there. What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See this line of code:

```
nextview *NView = [[nextview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

You use a nil as nib name to create your next view. Have you overwritten initWithNibName of the nextview to give a nib name?

Comment: but when i click on button next view also shown to me and labels and button on nextview also shown to me how it is overwritten

Answer (score 0):

There i so many method through which you can pass data from one view to another. in this Tutorial there is brief discription about this method Which you Want Check it [Tutorial Source Code](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/)

Answer (score 0):

do you init you property your member(such as name) when call 
nextview *NView = [[nextview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; if you init them in viewdidiload or other function about view，then they will be initialized  after 
you call    [self presentModalViewController:NView animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

See apples documentation for initWithNibName

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The nib is not loaded until its view is accessed. For additional initialisation use viewDidLoad.

Meaning, the outlets are just not set directly after initWithNibName.

So, one of the things you could do is add a reference to the first viewController as a property in nView and in viewDidLoad of nView you set the labels according to the first VCs labels.

On a side note: your naming convention is wrong. Use Uppercase for classes and lowercase for instances of that class ie it should be

```
Nextview *nView;
```